# ListViewAdapter AsyncTask executing error

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, listview-adapter

I dont know why my code does not work?
It is a part of listviewadapter code:
[http://pastebin.com/wFBCpCgd](https://pastebin.com/wFBCpCgd)

And it is PutBitmap code: http://pastebin.com/mpZqEGus

And i have got this error:

```
 08-20 08:45:24.607 27198-27217/com.example.bogna.hogmessanger  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.bogna.hogmessanger, PID: 27198
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:1028)
at com.example.bogna.hogmessanger.PutBitmap.doInBackground(PutBitmap.java:45)
at com.example.bogna.hogmessanger.PutBitmap.doInBackground(PutBitmap.java:17)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

why?
Please help. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: But i dont know what is null

Comment: `img` is `null` in your `PutBitmap` class

Comment: But why it is null?

Comment: It is not null i am checking this and it is not null

Answer (score 0):

your

```
img
```

Bitmap object is null. Make sure it should not be null and you can also implement the check like this:

```
if(img!=null && !img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut)){
        isOk = false;
}
```